# PayPal donation URL with cover fee checkbox on

Tags: php, url, paypal

A PayPal account can have different email addresses: each of them reserved for receiving specific donations. This allows the account owner to sort them easily, because he can export a CSV report and filter donations by the recepient email address chosen by each benefactor.

To receive donations for a specific email address, I used to manually build a direct URL in this way:

> ...paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=**ADDRESS1@EMAIL.EXT**&lc=US&item_name=**Donation+custom+purpose**&no_note=0&cn=&currency_code=EUR&bn=PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHosted

However, the new PayPal donation button builder also gives the opportunity to add a surcharge to the donation "to help offset the cost of processing": [screenshot of PayPal cover fee checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIrDX.png).

Unlike the previous one, this page can be reached from a link created by PayPal:

> ...paypal.com/donate/?hosted_button_id=*************

But donation URLs based on button ids cannot direct money to those specific email addresses.

So the question is:

1. Is there a way to manually create a donation URL link the first one, that also activates the cover-fee option?
2. Alternatively: is there a way to create a custom donation button linked to a specific email address?

---

Here is the HTML code block of the "cover-fee" checkbox:

```
<div class="ppvx_checkbox___3-6-2 cover-fee-checkbox">
   <input class="ppvx_checkbox__input___3-6-2" type="checkbox" id="cover-fee-checkbox" name="coverFee" data-testid="cover-fee-checkbox" value="false">
      <label class="ppvx_checkbox__label___3-6-2 ppvx_checkbox__label--with-svg-icon___3-6-2" for="cover-fee-checkbox">
         <span class="ppvx_checkbox__check-icon-container___3-6-2">
            <span class="ppvx_icon--svg___6-7-8 ppvx_icon--size_xs___6-7-8 ppvx_checkbox__check-icon___3-6-2">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 18 18" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor">
                  <path d="M5.566 14.417l-3.272-3.266a.996.996 0 0 1-.001-1.414 1.002 1.002 0 0 1 1.414-.002l2.566 2.561 8.02-8.004a.998.998 0 0 1 1.416.001 1.001 1.001 0 0 1-.002 1.415L6.98 14.417a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 0z"></path>
               </svg>
            </span>
         </span>
         <span>I’d like to add <strong id="fee-amount"></strong> to my donation to help offset the cost of processing
         </span>
      </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answers are no.

- You cannot create a "hosted" button that accepts a URL parameter to pay a different account/email address.
- You cannot create a custom/unhosted button or url that will show the checkbox for fees ("I’d like to add to my donation to help offset the cost of processing")